# Docker build with laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm getting error with my docker image after building the docker containers.

on docker-compose up -d command, the application is connected to a database.

but when I tried to run docker build -t to make an image
and run it, I got 500 internal error php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:7.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Install Laravel framework system requirements (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading)
RUN apk add oniguruma-dev postgresql-dev libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        ctype \
        fileinfo \
        json \
        mbstring \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        tokenizer \
        xml

# Copy Composer binary from the Composer official Docker image
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT /app/public
ENV APP_ENV production

# Copy existing application directory contents to the working directory
COPY . .
RUN composer install

RUN composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# Optimizing Configuration loading
RUN php artisan config:clear
# Optimizing Route loading
RUN php artisan cache:clear

RUN php artisan view:cache

RUN chown -R application:application .
```

for additional details here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
 #php service
 php:
  build: 
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: dtltrcy_phpv1
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html
   - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
  networks:
   - laravel

 #nginx service web server
 nginx:
  image: nginx:stable-alpine
  container_name: dtltrcy_nginxv1
  ports: 
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html
   - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  depends_on:
   - php
   - mysql
  networks:
    - dataliteracyapp

 #mysql service
 mysql:
  image: mysql:8.0.21
  container_name: dtltrcy_mysqlv1
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
   - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
   - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  environment:
   MYSQL_DATABASE: database
   MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
   MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
   SERVICE_TAGS: dev
   SERVICE_NAME: mysql
  networks:
   - laravel

 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  container_name: dtltrcy_phpmyadminv1
  depends_on:
   - mysql
  ports:
   - "8081:80"
  environment:
   PMA_HOST: mysql
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  networks:
   - laravel

#docker networks
networks:
 laravel:
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I tried to change .env file with these.

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 ERROR -> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

DB_HOST=localhost ERROR -> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

DB_HOST=172.19.0.3 ERROR -> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation time out

Container IP using docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_id

Comment: Fixed the problem using host.docker.internal as DB_HOST.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, this is my Dockerfile and it works fine.

```
FROM php:8-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# install the necessary packages
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    nano \
    npm \
    g++ \
    git \
    zip \
    vim \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    nodejs \
    libpq-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    zip \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar

# copy the config file over
#COPY /server/apache/ports.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
COPY /server/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf

#COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
#COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# use custom configuration and disable built-in one
#RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2ensite laravel.conf
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf

# copy over the project files
COPY . /var/www/html

# change ownership of the files
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

RUN cd /var/www/html && npm instal && composer install && php artisan optimize

CMD ["/var/www/html/scripts/start-apache.sh"]
```

/scripts/start-apache.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -i "s/Listen 80/Listen ${PORT:-80}/g" /etc/apache2/ports.conf
sed -i "s/:80/:${PORT:-80}/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

apache2-foreground "$@"
```

/server/apache/vhost.conf (not relevant for your issue though, it is for changing the document root)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  laravel-app:
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=routes-db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=""
    container_name: laravel-app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - laravel-app-network
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=routes-db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=""
    volumes:
      - "./db:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - laravel-app-network

networks:
  laravel-app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

If I remember correctly, it was either something to do with either the packages/libraries or permissions. Check the line:

```
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

It makes sure you got the right permissions.

Sorry that I couldn't give more details.

Comment: thank you for the effort. but apt is for linux.
I already fixed my problem using host.docker.internal in DB_HOST